Multiple instances of static data causing Segmentation Faults in shared libraries
I have a C++ static library (lib_static.a) which defines
a few singleton classes and global static variables, like std::string and std::vector, inside a class that this singleton uses and accesses. For example, static const is declared inside the class and defined inside the translation unit.
This static library (lib_static.a) is built as a PIC (Position Independent Code).
If I link lib_static.a into 2 different shared libraries (liba.so, libb.so)
and then I link these 2 shared libraries to my dummy executable on Linux, I will get a segmentation fault. If I run valgrind it says that
there is an Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc() on those std::strings and std::vectors.
Why is that? What is wrong, and what is happening?
I know obviously that singletons are the first red flag, but I was just curious to understand the behavior behind shared libraries. Maybe that is relevant to the "static initialization order fiasco"?

We are going to need to see some code to discern what is really going on.  On a side note, the point of position independent code is to create shared libraries; not static ones.

@Jason -- the reason for the position independent code is that the static library (which is, essentially, a collection of object files) is used to create a shared library.

Static/global variables from a static lib would be "duplicated" by executable/shared libraries (i.e both liba abd libb would have its own copy of lib_static).So your singleton is no longer unique.

@Jarod42 That's what I thought. But that also means that there is a chance that the destructor can be called for the same static global object twice, right?

Those duplication should not generate memory issues unless you (wrongly) manually handle memory.

And that is why having globals/singletons in your code is a bad idea. You might have a go at a Meyer's singleton. But in general creating an instance of a class (with abstract baseclass/interface) in main and then doing dependency injection is a much more maintainable approach
